# The problem of Generalized Eigenvalues, How to solve $AV=V\Lambda$?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

The problem is how to solve $$AV=V\Lambda, \quad\quad (1)$$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix,
$V$, the "generalized eigen-vector-matrix", is $n\times q$,
and, $\Lambda$, the "generalized eigen-value-matrix", is $q\times q$. 
Given $A$ and $q$ the objective is to find $V$ and $\Lambda$. The requirement to filter out trivial solutions seems to be that $V$ has rank $q$.

One solution is when $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with some of the ordinary eigenvalues of $A$ on the diagonal; and $V$ a corresponding collection of ordinary eigenvectors of $A$. The focus of this question is to find other solutions.

In general $V$ is not square. The special case in which $A$ and $\Lambda$ are symmetric is of particular interest.

Equation (1) can be written in a block-matrix notation. It becomes a $q\times q$ block matrix $B$, where each block, $B_{ij}$, is $n\times n$. The diagonal blocks are $B_{ii}=A-\lambda_{ii}I$ and the off-diagonals are $B_{ij}=-\lambda_{ji} I$. The matrix $B$ is $qn \times qn$, but the blocks commute and [hence the determinant simplifies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) to the formula for the determinant of a  $q \times q$ matrix where each entry is replaced by the corresponding block of $B$. For example if $q=2$ then $$\det(B)=\det((A-\lambda_{11}I)(A-\lambda_{22}I)-\lambda_{21}\lambda_{12}I).$$ Setting $\det(B)=0$ produces one equation for the $q^2$ elements of $\Lambda$.

Comment: If $\Lambda$ is diagonal and $V$ is invertible, then $AV = V\Lambda$ holds if and only if the columns of $V$ are eigenvectors of $A$

Comment: We have a more general statement, then: if $AV = V \Lambda$, then every column $v$ of $V$ must be either $0$ or an eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Can you provide a reference. Also, $V$ is not necessarily a square matrix.

Comment: Regarding the case where $\Lambda$ is diagonal: suppose that $AV = V \Lambda$. Let $v_1,\dots,v_q$ denote the columns of $V$, and let $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_d$ denote the diagonal entries of $\Lambda$.
With [block-matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication), we have
$$
AV = A \pmatrix{v_1 & \cdots & v_q} = \pmatrix{Av_1 & \cdots & Av_q}.
$$
On the other hand,

Comment: $$
V \Lambda = \pmatrix{v_1 & v_2 & \cdots & v_q} 
\pmatrix{\lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & \lambda_2 & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0\\
0 & \cdots & 0&\lambda_q} = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 v_1 & \lambda_2 v_2 & \cdots &\lambda_q v_q}.
$$
So, each column $v_j$ of $V$ satisfies $Av_j = \lambda_j v_j$.

Comment: For any given $\Lambda$, we could consider the equation $AV = V \Lambda$. I think that to make this question tractable, some constraint should be placed on the nature of $\Lambda$.

Comment: Regarding solutions to this problem given a particular $\Lambda$, see the [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation).

Comment: Note also that whenever $\Lambda$ is diagonalizable, the problem can be reduced to the case of a diagonal $\Lambda$.